# EU self-employed, UK client, post-Brexit, should I charge VAT?

Tags: uk, germany, eu, vat

I have a sole-proprietorship registered in Germany and provide services to my customers. I am currently in negotiations with a UK client. Now that the UK left the European Union and that deals have been agreed upon between the two entities, should I charge the German VAT (19%) for my services and use an EU tax id? Or should I instead charge a UK VAT and use a UK id? Or something else?

Comment: For goods, the UK HMRC is insisting that UK VAT is charged at source - in the EU.  This is imposing a ridiculous load on EU businesses.  For services, the situation is unclear.

Comment: @Chenmunka May I ask you to provide a source for this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should, according to HMRC ("[Should I be registered for VAT?](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/vat-notice-7001-should-i-be-registered-for-vat/vat-notice-7001-should-i-be-registered-for-vat)")

> 9.1 NETP – definition
> A non-established taxable person (NETP) is any person who is not normally resident in the UK, does not have a UK establishment and, in the case of a company, is not incorporated in the UK.

> 9.2 UK establishment: definition
> A UK establishment exists if either the:
>
> place where essential management decisions are made and the business’s central administration is carried out is in the UK
> business has a permanent physical presence with the human and technical resources to make or receive taxable supplies in the UK
> We would normally consider a company which is incorporated in the UK to have an establishment in the UK as long as it’s able to receive business supplies at its registered office.

> 9.3 When an NETP must register for VAT in the UK
> If you make any taxable supplies (see paragraph 2.3) in the UK, you must:
>
> - register for VAT in the UK
> - account for UK VAT to HMRC